# Regexp or Grep in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Can you please tell me how to get the token value correctly? At the moment I am getting: `"1jdq_dnkjKJNdo829n4-xnkwe",258],["FbtResult`

```
   echo '{"facebookdotcom":true,"messengerdotcom":false,"workplacedotcom":false},827],["DTSGInitialData",[],{"token":"aaaaaaa"},258],["FbtResult' | sed -n 's/.*"token":\([^}]*\)\}/\1/p'
```

Comment: If this is JSON please post valid JSON.

Comment: Коля, I understand it is some incomplete JSON, right? Your main issue is that you did not match the whole string. When you use `sed` to extract values, you must ensure the entire string match. See [my solution demo](https://ideone.com/xIsKSO).

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the full string, and to get rid of double quotes, you need to match a `"` before the token and use a negated bracket expression `[^"]` instead of `[^}]`:

```
sed -n 's/.*"token":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
```

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `"token":"` - a literal `"token":"` string
- `\([^"]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value): any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars.

Comment: Also, see [my solution demo](https://ideone.com/xIsKSO).

Answer (score 0):

This replacement works:

```
echo '{"facebookdotcom":true,"messengerdotcom":false,"workplacedotcom":false},827],["DTSGInitialData",[],{"token":"aaaaaaa"},258],["FbtResult'
| sed -n 's/.*"token":"\([a-z]*\)"\}.*/\1/p'
```

Key capture after `"token"` found between quotes via `\([a-z]*\)`, followed by a closing brace `\}` and remaining characters after that as `.*` (you were missing this part before, which caused the replacement to include the text after keyword as well).

Output:

```
aaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

A grep solution:

```
echo '{"facebookdotcom":true,"messengerdotcom":false,"workplacedotcom":false},827],["DTSGInitialData",[],{"token":"aaaaaaa"},258],["FbtResult' | grep -Po '(?<="token":")[^"]+'
```

yields

```
aaaaaaa
```

- The `-P` option to `grep` enables the Perl-compatible regex (PCRE).
- The `-o` option tells grep to print only the matched substring, not the entire line.
- The regex `(?<="token":")` is a PCRE-specific feature called a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion. The expression `(?<=pattern)` matches a *pattern* without including it in the matched result.